# Expo is it necesary to build and download the JS bundle on every change

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a react native app in Expo, and every time I make a change I have to reload the project which builds and downloads the js bundle, which usually takes a minute - a couple of minutes.

It's frustrating because this really slows down my work flow. Does anyone know ways to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using expo client? have you ejected after using expo?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using the Expo client on my phone and the Expo XDE on my macbook. Have I ejected after using expo?

Comment: Did you use CRNA? Eject is a command to detach and have both android/ios folders managed manually instead of Expo managing for us.

Comment: I'm not actually sure in honesty. I did create the project recently so it's likely I used CRNA.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable "Enable Hot Reloading" property. This screen open with Ctrl+M key combination on android-emulator. If you enable it, saving changes showing immediately.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but then when you make a change, i.e changing an api call etc. You again need to reload the whole app.